# JSF Template Designing in SUN RI_1.101

Tags: jsf, user-interface

We are using JSF in UI.We need to develop Templates for designing.Can we develop templates in SUN RI1.1_01.If so,can any one tell me how to start?

Answer (score 1):

You must check out Facelets.

> Facelets provide a server-side templating facility that allows composing the actual view from several separate physical pages in a way that maximizes markup code reuse and eliminates redundancy among views.

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facelets
- https://facelets.dev.java.net/

However, you must consider upgrading your JSF version.